# rpart Complexity Parameter values

Tags: r, r-caret

rpart parameters can be found using getModelInfo

```
getModelInfo("rpart")[[1]]$grid
function(x, y, len = NULL, search = "grid"){
                    dat <- if(is.data.frame(x)) x else as.data.frame(x)
                    dat$.outcome <- y
                    initialFit <- rpart(.outcome ~ .,
                                        data = dat,
                                        control = rpart.control(cp = 0))$cptable
                    initialFit <- initialFit[order(-initialFit[,"CP"]), , drop = FALSE] 
                    if(search == "grid") {
                      if(nrow(initialFit) < len) {
                        tuneSeq <- data.frame(cp = seq(min(initialFit[, "CP"]), 
                                                       max(initialFit[, "CP"]), 
                                                       length = len))
                      } else tuneSeq <-  data.frame(cp = initialFit[1:len,"CP"])
                      colnames(tuneSeq) <- "cp"
                    } else {
                      tuneSeq <- data.frame(cp = unique(sample(initialFit[, "CP"], size = len, replace = TRUE)))
                    }

                    tuneSeq
                  }
```

the only parameter is

```
cp = seq(min(initialFit[, "CP"]), max(initialFit[, "CP"]),length = len)
```

But how can I get the `initialFit` and the `len`?

Searching elsewhere I found that cp can usually take 10 values from 0.18 to 0.01. But still couldn't find out where those values come from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're unsure about appropriate values for a parameter, you can make `caret` choose for you and use default values. Here is an example that works end-to-end without explicitly specifying `cp`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
library(forcats)

# Take mtcars data for example
df <- mtcars %>%
  # Which cars are automatic, which ones are manual?
  mutate(am = as.factor(am),
         am = fct_recode(am, 'automatic' = '1', 'manual' = '0'))

set.seed(123456)
fitControl <- trainControl(method = 'repeatedcv',
                           number = 10,
                           repeats = 10,
                           classProbs = TRUE,
                           summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

# Run rpart
# Tuning grid is left unspecified, so caret uses the default
tree1 <- train(am ~ .,
               df,
               method = 'rpart',
               tuneLength = 20,
               metric = 'ROC',
               trControl = fitControl)
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to explicitly specify `cp`, do so using the tuning grid:

```
tuneGrid <- expand.grid(cp = seq(0, 0.05, 0.005))
tree2 <- train(am ~ .,
               df,
               method = 'rpart',
               tuneLength = 20,
               metric = 'ROC',
               trControl = fitControl,
               tuneGrid = tuneGrid)
```

A question on **why** you should select **which** values for `cp` is probably better posted on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

---

**Update:**

To answer your follow-on question about the default values and the values I chose in my example, I recommend going back to the primary source of the modelling function. `caret` is a great package for convenience reasons, but all it does is making lots of algorithms more accessible through a shared syntax. If you have a technical question about `rpart`, consult the package manual [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/rpart.pdf).

As mentioned above, this type of question is better placed on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), where the focus is on maths, stats, and machine learning.

However, to give you a **tldr** here:

The choice of tuning grid parameters is always going to be arbitrary to some extent. The objective is to find the value that produces the best results for your specific problem, which in turn depends on your data, your algorithm, and your evaluation metric. Some common "rules of thumb" include to start with a wide range, identify the area with a likely maximum and then use finer intervals around that region. In your case it is relatively easy as you only have one parameter to optimise over. Just try a couple of values and see what happens. You can `plot` the fitted `tree` object (`plot(tree1)`) to see how your model improves as a function of the complexity parameter `cp`. Eventually you will start developing a "feel" and "intuition" for what might work.

Comment: I was trying to use the tuning grid but I don't know which values to choose, why did you choose 0, 0.05, 0.005? Another question that I always had is how do you know the default value of cp for example? is it 0.1? how can I find the default value of a parameter?

Comment: But the values I'm searching can't be found from here? cp = seq(min(initialFit[, "CP"]), max(initialFit[, "CP"]),length = len)

Comment: You don't need them. That is just what `caret` uses to choose `cp` automatically